# Catel, IMessageService seems not working on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, catel

The code below does not produce any effect in any context. Explanation would be very appreciated?

```
var messageService = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IMessageService>();
var result = messageService.ShowAsync("My message via the service");
```

Comment: If you feel you found a bug, please report it at http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Comment: At first thanks for Catel, I really like it.
But fact is you may not use any references to UI controls within async - await. It is foundation of TPL. All the UI has own thread.